# Shader error in 'TextMeshPro/Distance Field': failed to open source file: 'TMPro_Properties.cginc' at line 126 (on d3d11)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

The textmesh pro file is not loading in unity. I am making a project using arcore and due to some issue with textmesh pro I was not able to build it properly.

Answer (score 13):

Delete the old version of TMP in Asset folder...
than reopen Project & go:
Window -> TextMeshPro -> Import TMP essentials
than
Window -> TextMeshPro -> Project Files GUID Remapping Tool...
this will update the project and fix all missing TMP scripts...

+

Install Post Processing package from

Window -> Package Manager -> search and install post processing

Comment: ...and if that does not help, reimporting the shader does. At least for me it did.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution didn't work in my case. This might be because I have URP project specifically. Sharing in case it helps:

- Select `Edit -> Rendering -> Generate Shader Includes`
- Do a reimport of the shaders in TextMesh Pro by going to `Assets/TextMesh Pro/Shaders`, right-clicking and selecting `Reimport`

Answer (score 1):

This might be the issue with the TextMeshPro folder contents.

Try the following steps to resolve the issue.

- Delete the TextMesh Pro folder located under Asset folder from the project.
- Reopen the project.
- Import TextMeshPro by clicking on `Window -> TextMeshPro -> Import TMP essentials`

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, this solution does not work :(

Comment: Added; Even with this error, Text comes out well.. But  I am worried there is unexpected issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the TextMesh Pro folders and **DON'T reinstall the extra's**.